# Java FX binding properties issue

Tags: java, javafx, properties, binding

Recently i have started to learn Java FX. Right now i'm practicing properties binding. I use Inetellij IDE at the moment. I have a problem that i cannot solve and i don't understand what is wrong. I declared some Properties eg. StringProperty in Person class and created constructor and getters and setters as well. I'm trying to bind (or bindBidirectional) those properties in initialize method but i can't. When i put (as in the code) person.getNameProperty as an argument of a method bind or bindBidirectional there is an error. Could anyone help me with this? What should i do? I saw quite similar code written in Netbeans IDE and there was no such problem.

MAIN

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 350));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TextField nameTextField;

//other declarations

private Person person = new Person();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    nameTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.getNameProperty());


}
}
```

CLASS PERSON:

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.property.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;

/**
 * Created by User on 2018-02-16.
 */
public class Person {

//person's name
private StringProperty nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

//Other properties

//consturctor
public Person() {

}

public String getNameProperty() {
    return nameProperty.get();
}

public StringProperty namePropertyProperty() {
    return nameProperty;
}

public void setNameProperty(String nameProperty) {
    this.nameProperty.set(nameProperty);
```

}
}

FXML file looks fine - i just run the layout.

Comment: " there is an error" ....do you want to share it with us ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't bind to a string you bind to the property itself.

```
nameTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(person.namePropertyProperty());
```

And going to throw in some personal opinion here ;) IntelliJ is THE BEST IDE for Java development. There's your plug for the day.